# Cannot connect to server in SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I just upgraded from SSMS 2012 to 2016. The 2012 version works fine but I have VS 2015 for Desktop that is incompatible with it so I had to install SSMS 2016. After I removed files and programs related to the 2012 version, I can't connect to server ever since using SSMS 2016.

Here is my error:
[image]

My TCP/IP protocol is enabled and set to default port 1433. I also noticed there is no SQL Server service in my services. It it normal to not show up because I'm not yet connected? Please help.

Comment: check sql server configuration manager to see more details on services and update question

Comment: Sql Server Services IS EMPTY :O

Comment: @Stoleg It still shows same error message. It seems that I have no instance running in my services. Do I have to install something?

Comment: You've may have -  removed 2012 and haven't actually installed a  database instance component for 2016. Maybe try to rerun set up, ensure the Database Engine/Instance (sorry working from memory here not sure of the exact wording).

Comment: @dave brown I have rerun the setup on repair mode several times. And it's an automatic install meaning it only needs to execute once and it will finish on its own (without the "Next" buttons). Btw this is what I have downloaded : SQL Server Management Studio 16.5.3 release. It seems that it doesn't include the Databse Engine which is the cause of my problem

Comment: what @Stoleg is saying is irrelevant because the client just tryes ALL the protocols avilable and named pipes is the last one

Comment: @ejmtv, did you have Database engine installed on your pc? I just don't understand what did you have prior to "upgrade", SSMS only or Database Engine + SSMS?

Comment: SSMS is just a "window". It needs to connect to something (DB instance, AS/RS Instance) that's located somewhere, either locally or on another server. If you're trying to connect locally and there is no SQL Server service running or available at all, it's likely you have NO Database instances installed.

Comment: yeah. i think that's the problem. I hate it when everything you need is not in just one installer.

Comment: Ponder this scenario, you have an Azure instance of SQL and you need to connect to it via SSMS. You wouldn't want to download and install SQL Server, you have a SQL Server. SQL Server has dozens of individual components and addins (for VS, etc.) and the installer would be massive if it had everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented to this post. I downloaded another program called SQL Server Express 2016 which apparently contains what I need (Database Engine) which I might have removed prior to removing all of SQL server 2012's components.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express